# DateListPlot with multiple data sets and incongruous timelines?

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, plotting

I am using Mathematica to analyze some sales data for my company. (A copy of the available data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3e9t9uzbcohuo3/CSV-MMA.csv?dl=0).) We are trying to analyze the sales trends for each month by item.

DateListPlot works well with individual items, but I have not found a way to plot multiple data sets (i.e., different products) on one plot. We sell several thousand products, so being able to only view one product at a time is rather cumbersome. Since we didn't start selling all of our products at one time, the start dates are different for many of our items.

**Can I use DateListPlot to plot multiple data sets with different start times?**

(...if not, does anyone have any good alternatives?)

(Working) code:

```
(* This notebook is designed to find out our most popular products, both in total and in relation to time.  *)


ClearAll; (*Clear out any stale variables. *)
data = Import[
   "C:\\Users\\sales\\Documents\\Marketing\\Data\\CSV-MMA.csv"]; (* Organize \
and manipulate our data to make it simpler. *)
data = Delete[data, 1];
data = SortBy[data, data[[All, 1]]];
data = Split[data]
data = Flatten[data, 1];
data = Drop[data, {2, 4}];
data = SplitBy[data, First];

f[q_] := Sort@(Flatten@{#[[7]], #[[1]], #[[2]], #[[4]], #[[5]], #[[6]]} & /@ 
     data[[q]]);(* Here we sort our data further. After this, it should be \
ready for graphing or grid analysis. *)
multiPlot[c_] := 
 DateListPlot[c[[All, 6]], 
  DateString[c[[All, 1]][[1]], {"Month", "/", "Year"}], 
  PlotLegends -> c[[1]][[3]], PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
q[z_] := d[f[data, z]];
d = Map[f, {1, 2, 3}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateListPlot` can be used with datasets with different timestamps:

```
data1 = {{{2014, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2014, 10, 15}, 12}, {{2014, 10, 30}, 15}, {{2014, 12, 30}, 10}};
data2 = {{{2014, 9, 5}, 15}, {{2014, 9, 20}, 8}, {{2014, 11, 10}, 5}, {{2014, 12, 15}, 8}};

DateListPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

With OP/s data:

```
dt = Import["... your directory ... \\CSV-MMA.csv"];
labels = dt[[1, {7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1}]];
data = Rest[dt][[All, {7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3}]];
data = MapAt[DateList, data, {All, 1}];

groups = GatherBy[SortBy[data, First], Last]; (* group by SKU *)

Histogram[Length /@ groups, PlotLabel -> Style["Histogram\n Series Lengths", 16, "Panel"]]
```

[image]

```
groups = SortBy[groups, Length];              (* sort by series length *)
longgrps = Select[groups, Length[#] >= 10 &]; (* select long series *)
ttdt = Tooltip[{#, #2},
   Column[{Row[{"Title = ", #5}],
     Row[{"SKU = ", #6}],
     Row[{"Units Ordered = ", #2}],
     Row[{"Date = ", DateString@#1}]}]] & @@@ # & /@ longgrps; (* add tooltips *)
```

Plot two of the series:

```
DateListPlot[{ttdt[[1]], ttdt[[-1]]}, Joined -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 700, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[labels[[2]], 22, "Panel"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Plot all 61 series with 10 or more observations:

```
DateListPlot[ttdt, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 700, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[labels[[2]], 22, "Panel"], 
 ClippingStyle -> Directive[{Thickness[.01], Black}]]
```

[image]

---

Original post:

You can use `TemporalData`:

```
series1 = {19, 16, 9, 3, 7, 2, 17, 10, 6, 12};
timestamps1 = DateRange["May 24th 2013", DatePlus["May 24th 2013", {{9, "Week"}}], "Week"];
series2 = {10, 15, Missing[], 12, 14, 5, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, Missing[], 8, 9, 10};
timestamps2 = DateRange["April 15th 2013", DatePlus["April 15th 2013", {{14, "Week"}}], "Week"];

td = TemporalData[{series2, series1}, {{timestamps2}, {timestamps1}}];
DateListPlot[td["Paths"], Filling -> Axis, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! My sincere thanks for your innovative and thorough deconstruction of a difficult problem.

Comment: @Qu0rk, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept and kind words.